# Can you alter the table to change engine types in MySQL? (MYISAM to INNODB)

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, myisam

I would rather not drop my table entirely to create a new one, but I need to change the `ENGINE` type from `MYISAM` to `INNODB`for foreign key contraints.

- Can I do this on the fly with an `Alter table`? Or do I have to start from scratch with a new table?
- Would it matter if I already had data in that table which needs to be altered / dropped & recreated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual:

```
    ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I've done this many times with no effect on existing data.  But never hurts to back up your table beforehand.